# Creating a Blogpost Like/Dislike Button within Django/Wagtail

Tags: html, django, wagtail

I'm new to Django and Wagtail and have looked for a way to implement a "simple" like/dislike button on a blog entry page using Wagtail.

I included a total_likes IntegerField in my model for the page and would like to increment or reduce this int within the database when the user clicks a button on the html template.

The user is not supposed to be logged in. Most tutorials I've found deal with this only for registred users which is not something I want.

I would be glad if somebody could point me in the right direction. The models.py code is below.

I do not understand how to call a function from within a template.

```py
    class BlogEntry(Page):
        date = models.DateField("Post date")
        intro = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
        body = RichTextField(blank=True)
        tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogEntryTag, blank=True)
        categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=False)
        total_likes = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
        image = models.ForeignKey(
            "wagtailimages.Image",
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
            related_name="+"
        )
        streamBody = StreamField([
            ("text", blocks.StaticContentBlock()),
            ("quotes", blocks.QuoteBlock()),
            ("image_and_text", blocks.ImageTextBlock()),
            ("related_articles", blocks.RelatedArticlesBlock()),
            ], null=True, blank=True)
    
        sidebarBody = StreamField([
            ("text", blocks.StaticContentBlock()),
            ("quotes", blocks.QuoteBlock()),
            ("image_and_text", blocks.ImageTextBlock()),
            ("related_articles", blocks.RelatedArticlesBlock()),
            ], null=True, blank=True)
    
    
        search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
            index.SearchField('intro'),
            index.SearchField('body'),
        ]
    
        content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
            MultiFieldPanel([
                ImageChooserPanel("image"),
                FieldPanel('date'),
                FieldPanel('tags'),
                FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
            ], heading="Blog information"),
            FieldPanel('intro'),
            StreamFieldPanel("streamBody"),
        ]
    
    
        sidebar_panels = [
            MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel("sidebarBody"),
                ], heading="Sidebar Content")
            ]
    
        edit_handler = TabbedInterface(
            [
                ObjectList(content_panels, heading="Custom"),
                ObjectList(Page.promote_panels, heading="Promote"),
                ObjectList(Page.settings_panels, heading="Settings"),
                ObjectList(sidebar_panels, heading="Sidebar"),
            ]
        )
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.total_likes
    
        def likePost(self):
            self.total_likes += 1
    
        def dislikePost(self):
            self.total_likes -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

Welcome to Django and Wagtail, there is a lot to learn but hopefully you are finding it fun. The first thing to wrap your head around is how a website (browser / client) can talk to the server (Python code running Django/Wagtail). Even though your `Page` model has a `likePost` method, you will need to provide a way for your `Page` to handle this kind of request.

The web uses a system of HTTP requests, the most common being `GET` and `POST`, where `GET` is used to pull down data to show to the user, `POST` is used for when the website wants to send something back to the server.

Django's docs on [working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) may be a good place to start to understand this process a bit more. Once your website has a `form` (in the HTML template), you can provide a way to 'listen' to this form when submitted. Wagtail has a method that exists on all `Page` models that is called [`serve`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html#more-control-over-page-rendering) and it allows you to override the normal behaviour.

### Solution

In the solution below you will need to do the following:

#### 1. Add two `form`s to your template (e.g. `blog_page.html`)

- Remember to load the tags `wagtailcore_tags` so that you can access the page's URL in the form.
- For simplicity, two forms have been created, one with a button for like and another with a button for dislike.
- Both forms will use the `method="POST"` and the action (this is the URL to POST to) being the current URL.
- Each form contains a `csrf_token`, you can read more about this in the Django docs but this helps avoid some security issues.
- Each form contains a html `input` that is `hidden` with a name and value, we will use the `name` only in the server code to determine what button has been clicked.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
... BLOG CONTENT
    <form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="like" value="true">
        <input type="submit" value="LIKE">
    </form>
    <form action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="dislike" value="true">
        <input type="submit" value="DISLIKE">
    </form>
```

#### 2. Override the `serve` method in your `Page` model

The `serve` method on the `Page` model takes the argument `request`, which is the [Django request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/) and should return a response. Thankfully we do not have to think about how this response is built, just know that we must call the `super` (original) version of this after any logic.

- Check if the current request is a POST request and if so, then check what kind of value has been submitted, depending on the value call the `Page` method that matches
- Update the `likePost` and `dislikePost` methods to ensure that the model data gets Saved via `self.save()`

```py
    class BlogEntry(Page):
    # ...

    def likePost(self):
        self.total_likes += 1
        self.save() ## note: you may need to ensure you call save to update data

    def dislikePost(self):
        self.total_likes -= 1
        self.save() ## note: you may need to ensure you call save to update data

    def serve(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.POST.get('like'):
                self.likePost()
                # a form POST has been submitted with a value for 'like'
            if request.POST.get('dislike'):
                # a form POST has been submitted with a value for 'dislike'
                self.dislikePost()
        
        # ensure we call the super's serve method so that the page loads correctly
        return super(BlogPage, self).serve(request)
```

### Good to know

- As you have noted, this is a basic request that does not require authentication (sign in) to submit a like, however it is very possible you will get a lot of spam this way and you may want to consider other approaches (even third party systems) to work around this.
- This way of storing likes (as an integer) will also not give you much data, just a number at the current point in time, it might be worth tracking individual submissions and then providing a tally to the UI.
- Here is a great [overview of HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) from MDN that I have found to be a good reference for understanding how a server handles requests & responses.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Truly appreciated. I have started to read up on HTTP, forms and the DRF - probably not needed here but at later stages of learning surely something I will need to look into anyway. As to the spam, this system is not intended to go online anyway. My goal is to isolate this simple problem, solve it and build on it by later adding authentication etc. My preferred way of learning is to tackle small issues in isolation. Again thank you a lot for your answer and your time! Cheers!

Comment: No problems, glad to hear it helped.